# Import CSV files into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import

I would like to ask for your help with the following:

I have CSV files exported from a software application that I need imported in Excel to analyse the data. Daily are generated 40-50 CSVs. For now I do this manually through "Get External Data from Text". The code recorded during the import is:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;SYSTEM:Users:catalin:Documents:LINELLA:WH Analytics:data:pick 01-18:050:Inquiry closed lists  SKU_0142.csv" _
    , Destination:=Range("A1704"))
    .Name = "Inquiry closed lists  SKU_0142"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ";"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .UseListObject = False
End With
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("A1710").Select
```

I want to be able to import automatically all CSV files from a selected folder where I'll put new files and launch the import process. Each file should be inserted immediately after last row of the previous files.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe [this Add-In would](http://superuser.com/questions/307496/how-can-i-set-excel-to-always-import-all-columns-of-csv-files-as-text/527894#527894) be useful? You still have to select the last row manually (CTRL+Down), but the rest will be automatically.

Answer (score 9):

Put the code you recorded in a function, replacing the static file name with a variable, then call that function for each `*.csv` file in the folder. The get the example below to work you need to save a file with this macro in the same folder as the csv files. For my quick test I had to replace the separator from `;` to `,`, and to remove the last row `.UseListObject = False`.

```
Sub ImportAllCSV()
  Dim FName As Variant, R As Long
  R = 1
  FName = Dir("*.csv")
  Do While FName <> ""
    ImportCsvFile FName, ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 1)
    R = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
    FName = Dir
  Loop
End Sub

Sub ImportCsvFile(FileName As Variant, Position As Range)
  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
      "TEXT;" & FileName _
      , Destination:=Position)
      .Name = Replace(FileName, ".csv", "")
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
      .TextFilePlatform = xlMacintosh
      .TextFileStartRow = 1
      .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
      .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
      .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
      .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
      .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
      .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
      .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
      .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
      .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
End Sub
```