# Combine multiple csv into one workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 files named inp1.csv, inp2.csv, inp3.csv, inp4.csv in the same folder.

I need combine these files into a single workbook where each file should be in a separate sheet.

Comment: So what's the problem?  There's no question here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import CSV files into Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17899897/import-csv-files-into-excel)

Comment: Yes, You can use that to merge multiple csv to one and then import the data from single csv to excel. Or you can do is import data from multiple csv's into workbook. Check this URL: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can look at a similar question here: [Merging a large number of csv datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27263917/merging-a-large-number-of-csv-datasets/32309479#32309479)

If I understand you correctly, you wish to take multiple csv (i.e. text) files and join them into one. You will then open the resulting csv files in Excel. Is that correct? I should point out the Excel csv's have one tab (worksheet). To get each csv into a separate tab you would need to work with xlsx files.

For the solution referred to above, if you are working in Windows you need to install gawk. It works beautifully in the Windows command line or the PowerShell environment.