# Scraping Google Finance using WINHTTP

Tags: excel, vba, finance, getelementsbyclassname, winhttp

I am trying to scrape the company name in google finance into my excel file. However, it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

```
Sub get_name()

  Dim oHtml As HTMLDocument
  Dim oElement As Object
  Dim i As Integer

  Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

  With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    'On Error Resume Next
    For i = 0 To 29
      .Open "GET", "https://finance.google.com/finance?q=" & Range("A32").Offset(i, 0).Value, False
      .send
      oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText

      Range("H32").Offset(i, 0).Value = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("appbar-snippet-primary")(0).innerText              

      Next i
    End With    
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  *"How to scrape web data"* is probably the ***most asked***  VBA/Excel question on this site; you'll get further than you have, with just a quick search. Check out the [tour] and there are also important tips in [ask] as well as tips about **providing examples** at [mcve].  We like to see that some effort has been made in finding a solution before asking for help (on a _specific_ problem), so please include details about what you've tried so far when you [edit]. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Also, **please define: *"doesn't work"***

Answer (score 0):

Unless your question is missing your *actual* objective, there's no reason to load individual Google Finance pages to retrieve company names based on their stock symbols.

> **CSV list of *all* Symbols, Company Names, Price, Sector, etc., for:**
>
> - [NASDAQ](https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nasdaq&render=download)
> - [NYSE](https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-name.aspx?letter=0&exchange=nyse&render=download)
> - [AMEX](https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=AMEX)
>
>   *<sup>([Source](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx))</sup>*

Why don't you create an Excel sheet (or Access DB) with a list of symbols & companies, and then on your sheet use a `VLOOKUP` ([Worksheet Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) or [VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel)) to find the ones that you need?

If there's some other reason you specifically need to scrape individual pages, there are a ton of examples on this site and others.

**This should get you started:**

- Stack Overflow: [Search for Excel/VBA Scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bexcel-vba%5D%20or%20%5Bvba%5D%20or%20%5Bexcel%5D%20or%20%5Bexcel-2016%5D%20or%20%5Bexcel-2010%5D%20scrape) (sorted by most votes)
- Stack Overflow: [Programmatically import CSV into Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17900384/8112776)
- Wikipedia: [List of Stock Exchanges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stock_exchanges#Major_stock_exchanges)
- NASDAQ: [Company List](http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx)
- Microsoft: [`VLOOKUP` Worksheet Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
- Microsoft: [`WorksheetFunction.VLookup` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel) (VBA)